# Setting Scroller on TextView for vertical scrolling

Tags: android, textview, vertical-scrolling, scroller

I am trying to implement a sort of vertical scrolling TextView by setting a Scroller on it.  The following code works on my device which runs Android 2.3 but it does not work on devices running Android level 15.  Any ideas why?

```
Private TextView tenthsTxt;
Private Scroller tenthsScroller;
....

tenthsTxt = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tenths);
LinearInterpolator scrollerInterpolator = new LinearInterpolator();
tenthsScroller = new Scroller(this, scrollerInterpolator);
tenthsTxt.setScroller(tenthsScroller);
tenthsScroller.startScroll(0,0,0, 59);
tenthsTxt.invalidate();

....
```

The xml for the TextView looks like this:

```
    <TextView 
    android:id="@+id/tenths"
    android:background="@drawable/tenths_digit_holder"
    android:text="0\n1\n2\n3\n4\n5\n6\n7\n8\n9\n0"
    android:textSize="25dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:paddingTop="5dp"
    android:paddingBottom= "5dp"        
    android:layout_width = "30dp"
    android:textStyle="normal"
    android:layout_height="43dp"                
    android:textColor="#ffff0000" />
```

On Android 2.3 the TextView scrolls vertically by the correct amount.  On Android devices running 4.03 the TextView does not scroll at all.  To be sure, a y-displacement scaled to the pixelDensity of the devices was also used - the results were the same with no scrolling movement observed on Android 4.03 devices.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure what you are trying to do, do you want this text to autoscroll up/down like credits in a movie?

Comment: Thanks for responding.  This is a simple test I used to evaluate the ability of the TextView to vertically scroll its content by 59 pixels.  This test is called in the onCreate() function.  The application uses tenthsScroller.startScroll(0,0,0, y) later on where y is a calculated value.  The test and the call to tenthsScroler.startScroll later in the application does not show any scrolling on Android 4.03 but works fine on Android 2.3.  And in answer to your question, yes it should scroll like a credit in a movie but the scroll should be instant since I did not set a duration.

Answer (score 0):

```
<ScrollView 
    android:id="@+id/scrollView"
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:scrollHorizontally="false"
    android:ems="10">
    <TextView 
            android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" 
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
</ScrollView>
```

Where scrollView has fixed size and textView's height align's to their parent.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it by programing

```
    txtView.setMovementMethod(new  ScrollingMovementMethod());
```

Comment: **I tried adding the following:**  



    `tenthsTxt.setMovementMethod(new  ScrollingMovementMethod());`  

Unfortunately, scrolling still does not work on a Galaxy S3 running Android 4.03 but it runs on a device running Android 2.3

Answer (score 0):

I know what you want. Here is a good source code example of what you need:

It contains Things like:

Vertical Autoscrolling
Text Entry
ListView
ListView Listeners
15+ Commands (Really Easy To add More)
Basic User Interface
Fake File System
Button Listeners
and More...
Download the Source Code Here:

http://www.fileswap.com/dl/0L8nU0kSFD/

If you want to see what it looks like have a look here:

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.coGame.consoletest&hl=en